# How do I implement a inp = input and print to a discord.py code?

Tags: python, discord.py

Python 3.6
Tensorflow 1.15

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to "port" this chatbot to a chat in a discord server, but I don't know exactly how to do it. I tried multiple solutions like changing the inp = input("") to the message.content == () or message.content.find == () and tried to make the bot read the message in the channel instead of reading the direct message.

Here is the raw section of the code I want to change that worked in the CMD:

```
    print("(say quit to leave the bot)!")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']

        print(random.choice(responses))

chat()
```

Some of my tries just evolved me trying to place some of the codes I found in the discord documentation directly in my code, I starter importing discord and messing around with the codes I found

```
    print("(say quit to leave the bot)!")
    while True:
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "":
    if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break
    results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
                responses = tg['responses']
await message.channel.send(random.choice(responses))
```

In my head it made sense and that I was going in the right path, I tried a lot of positioning of theses lines in different ways and changing message.content to Client.wait_for() but never worked.

Here is the entire working code for a better context >> https://gist.github.com/FlameinfirenBr/4db6fc5e736796233bb85b3422fac8a3

First time posting here so I don't really know what to give as information, so ask me anything and ill try to answer fast.

Edit: I already have done the bot implementation in my code, the bot get online and react at simple comands like

```
import discord


def read_token():
    with open("token.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines[0].strip()


token = read_token()
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!hi":
    await message.channel.send("hello")
client.run(token)
```

I read some of the complex part of the discord.py rewrite documentation and didn't see anything useful for my "problem", seems like this is just a basic "problem" I cant figure out how to solve.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn’t a free “do-it-for-me” code “porting” service. Generally, questions here are expected to demonstrate good-faith attempts at researching and solving the problem at hand prior to posting, along with specific detail as to why the previous attempts did not meet your requirements. See also: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @esqew I don't know how to properly formulate a question because I'm not even native English speaker, I'm trying to find someone that can explain how to use proper lines in proper places, I searched for almost a week and tried more than 30 different "solutions", and even changed the versions of all my components to try and change the code to work in discord, it was more than 50 tries and nothing worked.

Comment: The issue is not with your English, the issue is that the question demonstrates none of your “50 tries”, or the error messages/behaviors returned as a result of those 50 tries. Knowing “how to use the proper lines in proper places” is indicative that you may want to review your fundamentals and Python syntax before continuing to implement these requirements. Additionally, you should review the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as the descriptions of the properties and methods should give you plenty of hints on the “proper places” for these “lines”.

Comment: @esqew if the issue is the post don't demonstrate my research, how can I improve it?, I don't think pointing issues and making me question what is wrong with something I don't even know what is wrong at the first place will make a difference, I will appreciate any help and learn anything you will say to me. About my fundamentals, as I said in the post i am a beginner, my fundamentals are 2moth fresh in my head and I try to practice every single day and this bot is "my" first project and I'm asking for help.

Comment: The point of posting your previous attempts is (a) to allow the community to avoid duplicating your previous efforts, (b) to enable the community to point out mistakes in your approach or implementation that will enable you to solve your problem and learn from said mistakes, and (c) show a good-faith attempt at solving the problem rather than just expecting an answer for no effort.

Answer (score -2):

Well for starters make a bot on [discord.com/developers/.](http://discord.com/developers/.)

import discord and from discord.ext import commands (trust me it's a time saver).
After connecting your bot you can also hook up a database that stores your user 'answers' or just save it in a json whatever works for you. And as others have stated if you wrote the code you should probably know where to put find context and send message commands.

Btw your statement ".. I tried multiple solutions like changing the inp = input("") to the message.content == () or message.content.find == ().. " Try experimenting wtih async and bot events.  That would be a common approach toward solving this issue.

here is a link you should start using a lot more, it tells you everything you need to know and more ;)
[DiscordPy Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

EDIT:

try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "quit": #this will only prevent the bot from going on if the message is 'quit', I say you make some kind of a command to talk to the bot or store data somewhere if the bot is inactive or not
            break
    else:
        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])
            results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
            tag = labels[results_index]
    
            for tg in data["intents"]:
                if tg['tag'] == tag:
                    responses = tg['responses']
await message.channel.send(random.choice(responses))
```

Comment: ty for the help, ill try that

Comment: discordPy has built in bot event on_message, which passes the context, author, channel etc.., so try using that, you're welcome but please read the documentation otherwise you won't be able to set it up

Comment: okay, ty again for the help, about the "Your code is a mess to go through haha.." do you have some tips to organize better my code, or just practicing will make me better at that?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked - I guess it's explaining how to get to the answer.  Seems to answer the question "how do I get started writing a Discord bot?", which is not what was asked.

Comment: Well he did not implement a bot. My bad i saw he used on message now, but he still did not implement a bot

Comment: It kinda worked, i got some warnings and errors but i did some tweaks and it worked, ty very much